# pandas: Extracting only the month-day values for rows from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to plot a line graph for my data however the x-axis becomes extremely tight together due to the long date format (Y-M-D), and I've checked the data type for 'date' and it returned:

```
In[200]: df['date'].dtypes
Out[200]: dtype('O')
```

So my 'date' values are:

```
date
----
2020-04-12
2020-05-13
2020-02-02
```

but I want to extract only the month and day to make the column look like

```
date
----
04-12
05-13
02-02
```

How should I do this? I apologise for dupes as I couldn't find anything similar due to my datatype being 'O'. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second ist by indexing `str[1]`:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split('-', n=1).str[1]
#if dates objects
#df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.split('-', n=1).str[1]
print (df)
    date
0  04-12
1  05-13
2  02-02
```

Or convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

Comment: It worked but at the bottom i get an error saying ```<ipython-input-271-c98daeb9451b>:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead```

Comment: @xsmith - this error means there is some filtering before  my solution, is possible post code before `df['date'] =...` ?

Comment: @xsmith - Need `.copy()` if some filter like `df = df[df.a  > 10].copy()`

Comment: Never mind it's due to  redundant variable xD sorry for the confusion!